# Left Join; Only if there is at least one matching record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join two pairs of tables. If there is an ID in Table1 that can also be found in Table3 I need to join the tables. If there is no matching ID from Table1 in Table3, I need to not join the tables.

Ex.

If there is at least one id in Table1 in Table3; do something that is effectively this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table4 AS t4 ON t3.ID = t4.ID
```

If there are no IDs that match between Table1 and Table3; do something that is effectively this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: You say " If there is no matching ID from Table1 in Table3, I need to not join the tables." but then go on to say you need a join of table1 and table2, in that case. And in what way are the tables "two pairs"? It's not at all clear what you want...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul sounds like they only want the fields from table 3 and 4 in the result set if they're not all NULL

Comment: It's not clear what you want. @JamieD77's guess is a reasonable one. OP, can you confirm that that is what you're after (not having those columns), or are you interested in some change in the rows as well?

Comment: @JamieD77 is correct. Apologies for my unclear-ness; I need to join Table3 and Table4 to Table1 and Table2 only if there is a match of IDs from Table1 in Table3. The code snippets are representative of what I am after. The 'two pairs' was simply referring to Table1 and Table2 always being together as well as Table3 and Table4 always being together. 
Thank you all for replying and coming to my aid.

Comment: is this something you're trying to do in a stored proc/function/view?

Comment: i would say the same... have it on an SP or a table-valued function or view.

Comment: It is for a function for a dataset to generate reports. I am very sure that this can be done in a better way - on whole. I am iterating and improving as I go. I believe @tab-alleman has provided what I needed. Thank you all again.

Comment: What you ask for results in different columns in result.. what's wrong with first select? Which gives you single column structre and you can check if there's any row by *t3.ID is null*

Comment: Like most things, there are a lot of details of this that are not included as they would only detract from the question. In this matter, it isnt possible to even have a single column structure. There are actually 21 different tables that will be used, for different reports, as Table1. Also, Table3 and Table4 include custom user controlled fields that may not exits or there may be many. suffice it to say, there is a lot more going on that the simplified question reflects. @ramazan-binarbasi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just translating your question into SQL, you can do this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T1.ID=T3.ID)
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID
    LEFT JOIN Table4 AS t4 ON t3.ID = t4.ID
ELSE  
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```